# How to use progresbar with handler to update main UI in android?

Tags: android

I need to display ProgressBar on button action and also need to update same activity page after successful action. ProgressBar is getting displayed but it hangs (it interrupts and hangs) on action process. Circle bar does not animate.

Code sample : ProgessBar is added in layout xml

```
<ProgressBar
   android:id="@+id/loginProgressBar"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:visibility="invisible"
   android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />
```

Code behind : on button action

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if(loginProgressBar ==null)
    {
        loginProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.loginProgressBar);
    }

    loginProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    myHandler.post(new Runnable() 
        {             
            public void run() 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}
```

It seems that myHandler is updating main UI and at the same time. ProgressBar is also part of Main UI, so it hangs.
Please provide solution so that ProgressBar works without any interruption.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Take a look at the example in the link provided, it is exactly what you are looking for !

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hi i also did using AsyncTask..but got same result...Actual problem is when i start updating Main UI, progressbar do not progress because it is also part of main UI(Main UI runs in same thread)....if you have any alternate approach please provide with sample code